# how to sort products by colour and then by manufacture on magento 2?

Tags: magento2, products, sorting

On a magento **product page** **category page**, i want to seperate the products by colour, then i want to show a manufacture first,
eg,

black 
black

cyan
cyan

magenta
magenta

etc,

the first color in each I would want to show a manufacture first then anything else with the color.

How can I achieve this?